# Trouble with Injecting Content Scripts into Chrome Tab (Manifest V3)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome Extension that needs to detect DOM events (click, mouseover, etc.) on any tab the user switches to or opens during a recording session. The way that seems most appropriate to do this is using the `scripting` API to inject a script that set's the appropriate event listeners and can post messages back to the `chrome.runtime` API to collect data.

However, I'm unable to inject the content Script successfully. My project is a Vue3 + Vite + Manifest V3 Chrome Extension, and in my `background.js` on the appropriate `chrome.tabs` listeners I'm executing:

```
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId },
    files: ['src/content_scripts/events.js']
  });
```

The documentation clearly states that a relative path from the directory root is required. However, no matter how I structure that path, it says the file isn't found.

The exact error I'm receiving is:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not load file: 'src/content_scripts/events.js'.
```

Also, my `manifest.js` file is:

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "walkthrough.ai capturer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon16.png",
    "32": "icons/icon32.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon128x128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "desktopCapture",
    "tabCapture",
    "scripting",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs"
  ],
  "host_permissions": ["https://*/*", "http://*/*"],
  "action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "icons/icon16.png",
      "32": "icons/icon32.png"
    },
    "default_title": "Open Options"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "src/background/index.js",
    "type": "module"
  }
}
```

Any ideas on what could be happening?

Thank you

Comment: What is the exact error message? Do you have the scripting permission in your manifest?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just updated the question with the info.

Comment: If you try to manually open a tab with the URL chrome-extension://<your ext id here>/src/background/index.js does it appear?

Comment: Just tried that and yes it does.

Comment: I meant to ask you to try chrome-extension://<your ext id here>/src/content_scripts/events.js Also, it might work if you put events.js at the top level, and not in any directory

Comment: Your bundler doesn't compile parameters of various API methods so you need to set the paths manually: not in `src`, but relative to the build directory, e.g. `content_scripts/events.js`. Open the destination directory and look at the real structure, don't just guess.

Comment: I just tried putting the file in the root directory and it gave the same error after updating the require path. @AndrewParks 

@wOxxOm my build directory is`/dist` a you saying treat it as a relative import from there or look at the built/bundled code and a relative path like that?

Comment: The root of the extension is the directory where manifest.json resides and from which the extension is actually loaded into the browser. Assuming it's `dist`, open it and look inside to see where your files end up, then use this relative path. Don't prepend it with `/dist` or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some more digging on @wOxxOm 's suggestion, I was able to figure it out.

The content script wasn't showing up in the build folder, which is where the scripting API was looking for it to be a relative import from.

In order to solve the issue, I put the content script in my `/public` folder so that it gets placed in the `/dist` folder when the project is built.

This worked for now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

How about using
`chrome.runtime.getURL('where content script is from you are calling this API')`
instead of moving the content script file to public folder?

That way I get my file path correctly after building the project.